# XAML view not updating when binding changes

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a XAML view bound to a ViewModel

When the view loads it sets the binding context to be an object (type GAME_TBL)

When the ViewModel loads, I await a message arriving with a unique ID

I then use this to calll an API and return a game object which I cast to replace the one that is bound

However, even tho debug shows me this is all working, and the PropertyChanged fires, the UI never updates

From the View:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <viewmodels:VotingViewModel/>

</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

.....

```
<Label Text="{Binding currentGame.GAME_NAME}" />
```

In the VotingViewModel:

```
public class VotingViewModel : BaseViewModel

{

    GAME_TBL gameSelected;

    public GAME_TBL currentGame
    {
        get {

            return _currentGame;


        }


        set
        {
            _currentGame = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_currentGame));
        }
    }

    public VotingViewModel()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Views.GamesView, string>(this, "Selected Game", (sender, arg) =>

        {
            gameID = Convert.ToInt32(arg);

            currentGame = loadGameInfo(); // this interacts with an API to set object specifics

        });

    }

}
```

In the BaseViewModel

```
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
    string propertyName = null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Name of property: " + propertyName);

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));


    }
```

Comment: `nameof(_currentGame)` is the internal backing field, NOT the public property you are binding to

Comment: Oh FFS, that's fixed it. Thanks so much

Comment: @Journeyman1234 You can mark the right answer which will help more people with same problem.

Comment: I cannot see how, only comments show as Answers, not replies to my post?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit BaseViewModel in the Model Class of GAME_TBL. And inside the class GAME_TBL, you need to specify each and every property in the following manner:

```
    private string _gAME_NAME;
    public string GAME_NAME
    {
        get => _gAME_NAME;
        set
        {
            _gAME_NAME = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GAME_NAME));
        }
    }
```

Each property should have a an internal backing property, as above.